# Delete all on left after cursor with keyboard shortcut - Windows 11

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, windows-11, powertoys

I'm trying to replicate on Windows 11 the same function that Cmd+Backspace does on Mac, that is to delete everything on the left on the same line as the cursor, with just one key combination.

Ctrl+Backspace does a similar job deleting a single word on the left (the same function Option+Backspace on Mac), but I would like to delete everything on the left.

I've looked online but I couldn't find any similar question.
I've looked into PowerToys but I cannot find a way to solve this as, since it only accepts two-key combinations, it does not accept "Shift + Home + Delete" (that should work as I expect to).

Comment: +1 for identifying that key combo -- you've done some preparation before asking the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through AutoHotkey I was able to script the action I wanted, here is the script that seems to work

```
^BS::
send {Shift Down}
send {Home}
send {BS}
send {Shift Up} 
Return
```

Answer (score 0):

*Powertoys* seems a bit limited in functionality, but there are a number of powerful third-party tools (Windows has been pretty much an open system, until recently), such as [Clavier+](https://gryder.org/software/clavier-plus/), [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/), and [alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/autohotkey/), that can perform an action with user-assigned keystrokes.

You could even assign the sequence you identified, <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Home</kbd><kbd>Del</kbd>, to <kbd>Windows</kbd><kbd>Back Space</kbd>, to keep it similar to that on the Mac.

Before installing *any* application, it's a good idea to check it for malware at [VirusTotal.com](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/upload).